# How do you generate a list on excel based on complex criteria when the data set is not unique?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

I am trying to build a excel sheet that automatically generates the list based on the 3 criteria (each criteria has a dropdown). Below is the template I created.

**Criteria list:**
[image: Criteria list]

Purpose, loan type and collateral type will be the 3 criteria. I would like to have the sheet auto populates the list from the data set I created based on those 3 criteria.

**Image of Data Set:**
[image: Image of Data Set]

The problem is that each data(A2 to A31) can have multiple purpose, collaterals, or product type. So we gave each item the 3 possible outcomes for each criteria. Also, if one of the criteria has "always required", I want to show that item regardless of remaining criteria. For now, i don't care about the category and items details column. Required items (A7) columns is where the list will be created.

I am not sure if this is even possible on excel but just any help would be appreciated. I know the explanation is lacking so if you have any questions I will answer right away. If the data set has to be re-organized, please advise how it should be.

Comment: As its written, I'm having a hard time connecting your data set to your desired input. What goes in the "Required Item" and "Item Details" columns in your output? Can you rephrase using the values we can see? Something like `I want to find all the rows in the data set where Purpose (A2) shows up in any of the columns F:H in the data set AND Loan Type (B2) shows up in [columns] AND any of the Collateral Types (C2:C5) show up in any of the columns I:K in the data set. Once I find those rows, I want to pull out [columns] and display them below.`

Comment: Now that I've rephrased it a bit, I can see that the easiest method may be to add helper columns to the data set to determine if each row meets the criteria. If you can end up with a single column that has TRUE/FALSE for whether or not the row matches, then it's pretty easy to use `FILTER()` to pull out just those values and the columns you want from that. IE, don't try to do all the fancy bits in one big formula, put simpler fancy bits in each row.